# How to get the average value of RGB single channel of multiple images with Numpy Python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to extract features of multiple images located in a specific folder ('image').
I want to insert this features (grayscale, R,G,B, alpha, height and width) into a table using *tabulate* package.
The main issue is to iterate over the folder and extract the average values of the single Red, Green, Blue channels and, also to obtain the value of gray (if an image is present in that scale). After that, I would like to insert all information  into the table. I am not able to do any of this operation.
I've tried a this code, but it gives me many pixels values.
I'd like to get the average value, so JUST ONE NUMBER for each channel.
Please, anybody can help?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2

for img in os.listdir(image_path):        
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_path, img))     
    r,g,b = cv2.split(img)
    rgb_img = cv2.merge((r,g,b))
    x,y,z = np.shape(img)
    red = np.zeros((x,y,z),dtype=int)
    green = np.zeros((x,y,z),dtype=int)
    blue = np.zeros((x,y,z),dtype=int)
    for i in range(0,x):
        for j in range(0,y):
            red[i][j][0] = rgb_img[i][j][0]
            green[i][j][1]= rgb_img[i][j][1]
            blue[i][j][2] = rgb_img[i][j][2]
```

I don't know any method else, can anybody suggests one? I would really appreciate.
Thank you

Comment: I don't see how this code outputs the mean pixel value. Can you be more specific in where you would like our help?

Comment: you are perfect right! This code doesn't output the mean. I just did that to try to extrapolate the channels but not the average value. My target is to obtain the mean value of R, G, B for each image in the folder without write manually the operation for every files, but, hopefully, iterate over. After obtained the single mean value of RGB for each image, insert the numbers into a table with "tabulate". Do I need to change everything or I can implement the current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the average values of the channels(R, G, B), and finally want to store it in a table using tabulate, you could do the following:

I will be using OpenCV(to load the images) and numpy(cuz why not)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from tabulate import tabulate

images = os.listdir('./Test')
num_images = len(images)

data = [] # using an array is more convenient for tabulate.

for i in range(num_images):
    img = cv2.imread('./Test/' + images[i])
        
    avgR = np.mean(img[:,:,2])
    avgG = np.mean(img[:,:,1])
    avgB = np.mean(img[:,:,0])
    
    data.append([images[i], avgR, avgG, avgB])
    
print(tabulate(data, headers=['img_name','R', 'G', 'B'], tablefmt='fancy_grid'))

'''
╒════════════╤══════════╤══════════╤══════════╕
│ img_name   │        R │        G │        B │
╞════════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ test1.jpg  │  49.3213 │ 112.408  │ 145.949  │
├────────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ test2.jpeg │  93.0038 │  94.4466 │  95.0824 │
├────────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ test3.jpg  │ 100.181  │  71.6575 │  66.4233 │
╘════════════╧══════════╧══════════╧══════════╛
'''
```

---

This is my Directory Structure:

[image: dir structure]

The code is present in the **movie scraper** directory. Hence i have used the path './Test'. The dot '.' represents the current dir.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried as you said...and it works, I get values for each channel.

Now, how can I understand which image the value refers? 
How can I insert the relative value to the table with "tabulate", referring to the right image?

Comment: Each images will have a name, so all you have to do is insert [img_name, avgR, avgG, avgB] into the table. You could use pandas to make a table(in pandas they are called dataframe). Use this link to read more about [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Comment: Hi, since my inefficiency in relating every image to the each channel, could you show a code example to understand better. I'd love that! :)

Comment: Edits have been made to my code. I have chosen a dictionary to store the values. You can use pandas dataframe or a numpy array. Also you can further extract and store features in a similar fashion.

Comment: Would you use this syntax  gray = np.mean(img[:,:,:])  to define if grayscale values are present

Comment: Grayscale images are 2D(as they dont have R G B channels). So to calculate the mean of the grayscale image you can simply do this : np.mean(img).

Comment: sorry for bothering: how can I print a table with tabulate module (professor wants tabulate), with the name of images as first column and the RGB channels as headers with relative values under them ( Headers: Name, R, G, B), relying on the dictionary previously created?

Comment: I removed the dictionary implementation as its better to use arrays when it comes to tabulate module. I initially used a dictionary as its prefered for pandas. For more upgrades to the table visit : [link](https://analyticsindiamag.com/beginners-guide-to-tabulate-python-tool-for-creating-nicely-formatted-tables/)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much again! Very kind

Comment: The way to help a person is by upvoting :)

Comment: I tried to vote the answer, but my reputation is too low for upvoting! When i get higher reputation I will for sure! In case of another way to vote your profile, please tell me!!! I'll be glad

Comment: ya you will need to reach 15 reutation i think.

Comment: Note that, according to https://sighack.com/post/averaging-rgb-colors-the-right-way, rather than summing up the components of the RGB color, you should sum their squares.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://sighack.com/post/averaging-rgb-colors-the-right-way the correct way to average RGB color values is to sum their squares rather than just take the mean. Example code in python is given below. Could probably be optimised but works for me.

```
def get_avg_rgb(img_file: str):
    import cv2

    img = cv2.imread(img_file)
    r_values = img[:, :, 2].flatten()
    g_values = img[:, :, 1].flatten()
    b_values = img[:, :, 0].flatten()

    Rsum = 0
    for r in r_values:
        Rsum += (float(r) * float(r))

    Gsum = 0
    for g in g_values:
        Gsum += (float(g) * float(g))

    Bsum = 0
    for b in b_values:
        Bsum += (float(b) * float(b))
    avgR = math.sqrt((float(Rsum) / len(r_values)))
    avgG = math.sqrt((float(Gsum) / len(g_values)))
    avgB = math.sqrt((float(Bsum) / len(b_values)))

    avgs = [avgR, avgG, avgB]

    return avgs
```

Comment: you've got **numpy**. why are you writing **loops**? that's pointless and wasteful. -- that's *closer* to the truth but still **not exactly "correct"**. what that does is transform the gamma-mapped (sRGB?) values into linear values... an exponent of 2.0 is close to 2.2-2.4, which is close to the true sRGB curve that most images and videos use, which is defined in two pieces, with an exponent of 1/0.45 for one section (and some offsetting) -- the page you link to isn't even hinting at this oversimplification. it's junk. the video they link to does mention the intricacies...

Comment: Great! Can you suggest some code so I have a better idea what you’re getting at?